# In Java, is it bad practice to instantiate an object multiple times in a loop?

Tags: java, instantiation

I am working on a Java project and a variable is instantiating as local variable over and over inside of a while loop.

```
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
    isFound = matcher.find();
    if(isFound){
      break;
    }
}
```

The problem is, local variable matcher is instantiating every time in the while loop until the loop's termination.

I was wondering, would this slow the process time?

Comment: It depends on the use case. In some cases, you just can't proceed without instantiating new objects in a loop

Comment: It's worth noting that you aren't actually instantiating anything in your loop here.  You are declaring a Matcher object reference to receive the return value from the pattern.matcher() call.  I.E. there's no `new` in the code you posted.

Comment: @geneSummons even though he does not use `new` key word directly, the `matcher` method inside `Pattern` creates `new Matcher(this,input)` and returns it. So technically , he is creating new instance there.

Comment: Tomato / Tomato.  "He's" not instantiating anything and neither is "his" variable.  The underlying library method is instantiating new objects, but as answers have pointed out, that's often unavoidable and the standard use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no. Often times, you need to do something like this. Of course, you do want to avoid spurious and excessive stack allocations because they aren't free, but there are many perfectly-fine circumstances where you will need to create an object within a loop.

There's also the difference between instantiation and declaration. In your example, `pattern.matcher(inputLine)` is your object instantiation; you're creating a new Matcher with that statement alone. `Matcher matcher = ...` is your declaration. If you're asking whether it's ok to declare a variable multiple times within a loop, it again depends on the context. Usually, this is fine and in fact preferable to declaring the variable outside of the loop, because the scope of every instance of that Matcher is (presumably) supposed to be limited to a single iteration of the loop. This scope mechanism can help you avoid making bugs later on in your application.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using your Matcher object seems to me that it should be instantiated outside the loop and then used.

Comment: and how would the Matcher object get the inputLine outside the loop?

Comment: @toongeorges The matcher can theoretically be instantiated with a dummy string, calling Matcher#reset(inputLine) in the loop would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

In this particular case, it's ok to do this. This is because `inputLine` is changing in each iteration of the loop. You can't do this without creating a new `Matcher` each iteration. Also, `Matcher`'s constructor just seems to do this:

```
Matcher(Pattern parent, CharSequence text) {
    this.parentPattern = parent;
    this.text = text;

    // Allocate state storage
    int parentGroupCount = Math.max(parent.capturingGroupCount, 10);
    groups = new int[parentGroupCount * 2];
    locals = new int[parent.localCount];

    // Put fields into initial states
    reset();
}
```

I wouldn't say that's a lot.

In other cases, where creating instances can be avoided, you should avoid creating instances. A good example of this is string concatenation in a loop.

Example:

```
String s = "";
for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) {
    s += Integer.toString(i); // string is immutable so this creates a new string every time.
}
```

You should use `StringBuilder` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The normative pattern for doing pattern matching in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is:

1. Instantiate a Pattern
2. For each input string s to be tested create a Matcher m via .match(s), as you are doing.
3. Test for a match via m.matches()/find() method in Matcher, as you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. For this particular case others have addressed your question. In general it's usually, but not always, better to instantiate an object inside a loop so that it gets cleaned up in young-generation collections. Java's GC is optimized for short-lived objects.

The scope of the variable needs to conform to the logic of the situation, not some dogma about "better". The object might outlive the variable, as for example in a loop like:

```
Result result = null;
for (int ix = 0; ix < limit; ++ix) {
  Result candidate = new Result();
  if (condition()) {
    result = candidate;
    break;
  }
}
if (result != null) { ...
```

Here, the `candidate` variable is out of scope after the loop. If assigned a non-`null` value, the `result` variable will point to an object that outlived its original reference. All the other candidates will be eligible for GC. (The example is contrived, but geared to illustrate the point.)

Exceptions are when initialization overhead is large, and not repeated inside the loop. If an object's construction is massive, and the loop only changes some small part of the object state without repeating the massive work, you might consider creating the object outside the loop.

How massive is "massive"? It's hard to know. But object creation is nearly free and young-generation GC also just about free. Dead objects do not contribute to young-GC overhead. When objects are tenured, GC overhead increases, so you want to keep lifetimes as short as needed.

Lifetime management is one of the Dark Arts of Java programming. You mostly won't go wrong, though, if you favor throwing away objects as quickly as possible. To deviate from this rule of thumb, you must measure the differences between different lifecycle tactics. There are some cases where keeping objects around longer significantly improves performance, but if you study them you find that the results were achieved with much experimentation and accurate metrics.